# Using "gifted" as a verb

Tags: verbs

You can say that you gifted someone something but is this usage correct?

> I've been gifted a new phone by my friend

Comment: Add a full stop and it’s a valid English sentence.

Comment: This example is totally grammatical, but I'd deduct a half-mark in an English essay (and not just for the missing full stop). 'Gift' is certainly a valid verb, and can be used benefactively (Arsenal gifted Brighton a corner; more generally A gifted/gift/gifts B C), but it is not totally interchangeable with 'give'. Its primary senses are   'grace/endow with', 'present formally' or (wryly, as in the above example) 'present on a plate'. I'd class it as pretentious here.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I was asking because my English teacher said it's completely wrong, saying "gifted" can only be used in a "spiritual"  sens, when someone is smart or was gifted with beautiful voice etc.